# What is the lowest level WinSock API available in the user mode? (For API injection trampoline.)

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, 64-bit, winsock

My goal is to intercept outbound TCP packets from a custom-built application that I do not have source code to. I need to adjust several parameters in the outbound data. It is an older application that the original company no longer sells and the developer is no longer available.

So I was planning to install an API injection trampoline into the [send()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) type raw WinSock API from my DLL that I can inject into the target process. But before writing such DLL, I decided to test this concept in my local process. So I did the following:

```
#ifdef _M_X64
//Simple code to install "API injection trampoline"
//Compiled as 64-bit process

static int WINAPI TestJump1(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags);
{
    //This part is just for debugging to make sure that my trampoline method is called
    //The actual "working" trampoline will involve additional steps to insure that the original method is also called
    ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Injected method called!", L"Debugger Message", MB_OK);
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}


HMODULE hModWS2 = ::LoadLibrary(L"Ws2_32.dll");
if(hModWS2)
{
    int (WINAPI *pfn_send)(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags);
    int (WINAPI *pfn_sendto)(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *to, int tolen);

    if(pfn_send &&
        pfn_sendto)
    {
        //Long absolute JMP
        //48 b8 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx   mov rax, 0xxxx
        //ff e0                           jmp rax

        BYTE subst[] = {
            0x48, 0xb8,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0xff, 0xe0
        };

        HANDLE hProc = ::GetCurrentProcess();

        VOID* pPtrAPI = pfn_send;
        //Also tried with 
        //VOID* pPtrAPI = pfn_sendto;

        //Make this address writable
        DWORD dwOldProtect = 0;
        if(::VirtualProtectEx(hProc, pPtrAPI, sizeof(subst), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect))
        {
            //Install JMP opcodes
            VOID* pJumpPtr = TestJump1;
            *(VOID**)(subst + 2) = pJumpPtr;
            memcpy(pPtrAPI, subst, sizeof(subst));

            //Reset it back
            DWORD dwDummy;
            if(::VirtualProtectEx(hProc, pPtrAPI, sizeof(subst), dwOldProtect, &dwDummy))
            {
                if(::FlushInstructionCache(hProc, pPtrAPI, sizeof(subst)))
                {
                    //Try to call our method
                    //int rz = pfn_send(NULL, "", 0, 0);        //This works!

                    //Try real test with the higher level API
                    //Download a web page into a file:
                    //This API must be calling raw sockets at some point internally...
                    //but my TestJump1() is never called from here...
                    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, 
                        L"http://microsoft.com/",
                        L"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file.txt", 0, NULL);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

So the code works fine, the `JMP` trampoline is installed and called alright if I call `send` method explicitly (as shown above) but my further assumption that a higher level API (i.e. `URLDownloadToFile`) would call it as well does not seem to hold true. My trampoline method is never called from it.

So what am I missing here? Is there an even lower WinSock API?

Comment: @Stargateur that is for UDP, not TCP

Comment: There's a number of different functions that can write to a connected stream socket, like `send`, `sendto`, `WSASend`, `WSASendTo`, `WriteFile` and `WriteFileEx`. These are all the same level. There are (undocumented) lower level interfaces than this but I wouldn't expect URLDownloadToFile to use them. You might want to consider using some sort of proxy to the intercepting, creating your own server to connect to and arranging for either DNS to give your server's IP address or give your server the IP address of the destination.

Comment: You might be interested in [Windows Filtering Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510.aspx) or perhaps its earlier incarnation, [LSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513664.aspx)

Comment: the lowest level sock api implemented in mswsock.dll - look for [`WSPStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742296(v=vs.85).aspx) - you need hook only this exported function from mswsock.dll and then replace some entries in [`WSPPROC_TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736553(v=vs.85).aspx) to own. you need how i view `lpWSPSendTo`

Comment: another option - not hook `WSPStartup` - but found in process heap `WSPPROC_TABLE` and hook (really replace pointer) here. this is not hard

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, but I don't know if `URLDownloadToFile` use UDP. Plus `sendto()` can be use on `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET` too.

Comment: @Stargateur: I tried with `sendto` (as was shown in the code) and it didn't get called either.

Comment: @Stargateur most URLs are accessed over TCP protocols, not UDP protocols. So `URLDownloadToFile()` is almost always using TCP.

Comment: @RossRidge: Sorry, I missed your comment. We are currently using a cobbled up proxy to address this. Unfortunately doing it a proxy-way limits us to unencrypted http-only connections. With my approach to intercepting WinSock API calls, hopefully, I'll be able to allow them to use encrypted `https` connection instead.

Comment: You can install a certificate that matches the one provided by your proxy to man-in-the-middle HTTPS connections. That's basically how Fiddler lets you monitor HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 1):

`send()` is not the only function available for sending TCP data using Winsock in user code. There is also:

- `WSASend()`
- `WSASendDisconnect()`
- `WSASendMsg()`
- `TransmitFile()`
- `TransmitPackets()`
- `RIOSend/Ex()`

At the very least, apps that don't use `send()` will *usually* use `WSASend()` instead, for use with Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports. That is usually good enough for most situations. The other functions are not used very often, but may be used in certain situations where higher performance is really needed.

Comment: Thanks. Can someone really use `WriteFile` to write to a WinSock (like you showed in your comment above)?

Comment: really all sendto go through `WSPPROC_TABLE.lpWSPSendTo` - we need replace pointer to this api to own in this table. and all

Comment: @c00000fd - you have (how minimum i know) 2 option - 1) hook `WSPStartup` before it called first time. 2) after `WSPStartup` is called - possible found `WSPPROC_TABLE` in heap

Comment: but RIOSend/Ex - this not hooked. so need hook `lpWSPIoctl` too for hook `WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO` return

Comment: @RbMm: Where is `WSPStartup` located? I can't seem to load it from `Ws2_32.dll`.

Comment: but i write that in mswsock.dll

Comment: @RbMm: My bad. Didn't see it.

Comment: @c00000fd - so you bad looking - mswsock.dll export `WSPStartup` in all windows versions

Comment: So, guys, thank you both! It looks like `WSPStartup` is called first and then `WSASend` repeatedly after that inside the `URLDownloadToFile` function. So now I'll move on to the "real" test with my actual app I started it all for. Need to write an injection DLL first. Quick question though -- it must call some raw socket API to communicate via TCP/IP, right? I see `libcurl.dll` is statically linked to it. That's probably where the WinSocks should be called from.

Answer (score 1):

the lowest level winsock api is implemented by [Winsock Service Provider Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741418(v=vs.85).aspx). during interface initialization the [WSPStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742296(v=vs.85).aspx) function is called from interface provider (this api must be exported by name from provider dll). for *MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] "{E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}"* it implemented in *mswsock.dll* by default - look more [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZdCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1473&lpg=PT1473&dq=%22E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192%22&source=bl&ots=ninRFdg8t7&sig=_wAGS3yxV_ostiHiZxsPN5NQ41I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqjveEnt_UAhWhCcAKHSBOAOMQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=%22E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192%22&f=false) (strictly said used dll registered in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\Catalog_Entries[64]` but by default, this is *mswsock.dll* )

[WSPStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742296(v=vs.85).aspx) return to `ws2_32` [`WSPPROC_TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736553(v=vs.85).aspx) - here the lowest user mode api which called. say for sendto - this is [`lpWSPSendTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742291(v=vs.85).aspx) function. so for hook all sendto you need replace [`lpWSPSendTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742291(v=vs.85).aspx) pointer in [`WSPPROC_TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736553(v=vs.85).aspx) to own. some api pointers returned via [`WSPIoctl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742282(v=vs.85).aspx). so you must replace `lpWSPIoctl` member in table to own and replace in result returned by original [`WSPIoctl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742282(v=vs.85).aspx) to own api. example for [RIO extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437226(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <ws2spi.h>
#include <mswsock.h>

LPWSPIOCTL g_lpWSPIoctl;
LPWSPSENDTO g_lpWSPSendTo;
LPFN_RIOSENDEX g_RIOSendEx;

int WSPAPI WSPIoctl(
                    __in   SOCKET s,
                    __in   DWORD dwIoControlCode,
                    __in   LPVOID lpvInBuffer,
                    __in   DWORD cbInBuffer,
                    __out  LPVOID lpvOutBuffer,
                    __in   DWORD cbOutBuffer,
                    __out  LPDWORD lpcbBytesReturned,
                    __in   LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
                    __in   LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine,
                    __in   LPWSATHREADID lpThreadId,
                    __out  LPINT lpErrno
                    )
{
    int r = g_lpWSPIoctl(s, dwIoControlCode, lpvInBuffer, cbInBuffer, lpvOutBuffer, cbOutBuffer, lpcbBytesReturned, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine, lpThreadId, lpErrno);

    static GUID functionTableId = WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO;

    if (
        !r 
        && 
        dwIoControlCode == SIO_GET_MULTIPLE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER && 
        cbInBuffer == sizeof(GUID) && 
        cbOutBuffer >= sizeof(RIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE) &&
        !memcmp(lpvInBuffer, &functionTableId, sizeof(GUID))
        )
    {
        PRIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE priot = (PRIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE)lpvOutBuffer;

        if (priot->cbSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(RIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE, RIOSendEx))
        {
            g_RIOSendEx = priot->RIOSendEx;// save original pointer to use
            priot->RIOSendEx = RIOSendEx;// this is your hook function 
        }

    }

    return r;
}
```

so we need hook [WSPStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742296(v=vs.85).aspx) function *before* it will be called first time by *ws2_32.dll*

Comment: Thanks. Just curious though, what if the original pointer to `lpWSPSendTo` is set to `NULL`?

Comment: @c00000fd no, `lpWSPSendTo` not set to 0. i think you look this table in static disassembler, not in runtime, when this table yet not initialized. however when `WSPStartup` is called - it ofcourse return full initialized table and `lpWSPSendTo` never 0, but valid pointer to `WSPSendTo`